# "Thriving" versus "Flourishing"

Tags: meaning, differences

A quick google gives us these two definitions:

> Flourishing: "developing rapidly and successfully; thriving."
>
> Thriving: "prosperous and growing; flourishing"

Taking those definitions into account, what is the difference between the two?

Comment: They're more closely synonymous than most synonyms.

Comment: Please do not ask questions that explicitly ask for subjective answers as they are off-topic. For this to be a valid question you should explain why the similarities of these dictionary definitions do not square with your reading or experience.

Answer (score 0):

In modern usage, the words are synonymous and can be used interchangeably. A botanist may prefer to use 'flourishing' when speaking about flowers, but that may be a bit pedantic.

### Flourish

Middle English: from Old French *floriss*-, lengthened stem of *florir*, based on Latin *florere*, from *flos*, *flor*- ‘a flower.’ The noun senses ‘ornamental curve’ and ‘florid expression’ come from an obsolete sense of the verb, ‘adorn’ (originally with flowers).

### Thrive

Middle English (originally in the sense ‘grow, increase’): from Old Norse *thrífask*, reflexive of *thrífa* ‘grasp, get hold of.’

Etymology provided by Google.

Comment: Sounds like the difference is in the relative amount of phosphorus and potassium in the linguistic soil.  One is about flowers, the other about roots.

Comment: I see you’ve been cultivating your commenting style; your mind is a veritable hothouse of budding ideas. :-)

Comment: 12-12-12... or a top dressing of natural bovine fertilizer.